# Multiprocessing makes closed tkinter gui pop up again

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multiprocessing

In my program I want a window to pop up first asking which files the user would like and then open the actual program. It works fine but when I try to activate the function in the other program the first one pops up and I have to close it for the actual function to start. I think this is due to the multiprocessing but i am not sure.

```
import tkinter as tk
import multiprocessing
from playsound import playsound
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

global Pianobool
Pianobool = False
def Piano():
    playsound(r'F:\Backup\Game.Develop\In.Develop\numbe.py\STEMOPLAYER/Piano.mp3')

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=Piano)

def awodijhaw():
    root =  tk.Tk()

    def PlayPiano():
       global Pianobool
       if Pianobool:
           global p
           p.terminate()
           Pianobool = False
           print('Paused')
           p = multiprocessing.Process(target=Piano)
       elif not Pianobool:
           p.start()
           print('Started')
           Pianobool = True
           p.join

    root.title('STEMOPLAYER')
    root.geometry("700x700")
    root.config(bg='#212124')
    Pianobutton = Button(root,bg='#007aff',fg='white',text='Piano',height=25, width=25, command=(PlayPiano))
    Pianobutton.place(x=550,y=250)
    title = Label(root, text="STEMOPLAYER",bg='#212124', fg='white')
    title.config(font=("Courier", 80, ))
    title.place(x=0, y=100)
    root.mainloop()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('STEMOPLAYER')
root.geometry("650x350")
root.config(bg='#212124')
#BOOLS
Pianobol = False

def choosePianos():
    Tk().withdraw()
    Pianofilename = askopenfilename()
    stringpiano = str(Pianofilename)
    pianochoice = Label(root,bg='#007aff',fg='white', text=stringpiano)
    pianochoice.place(x=30,y=50)
    print(stringpiano)
    Pianobol = True

def confirm():
    popupo = tk.messagebox.askquestion ('Are you sure','Are you sure you want to continue to STEMOPLAYER',icon = 'info')

    if popupo == 'yes':
        root.destroy()
        awodijhaw()

choosePiano = Button(root,bg='#007aff',fg='white', text="choosePiano",command=(choosePianos))
choosePiano.place(x=30, y=30)

Confirmbutton = Button(root,bg='#007aff',fg='white', text='COnfirm', height=2, width=10, command=(confirm))
Confirmbutton.place(x=330, y= 300)

root.mainloop()
```

Here is the code the playsound mechanic works great on its own but fails when combined.

Comment: Why on earth are you using multiprocessing here at all?

Comment: (Either way, as the multiprocessing documentation says, you must guard the main entry point of your application with `if __name__ == "__main__"` if you use it.)

Comment: When you use multiprocessing, you need guard the code that should only be executed in the main process inside a `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Comment: I used multiprocessing because I didnt find a better way to start and stop it when I wanted also I needed to play multiple tracks at once which I didt include so it would be shorter and easier to understand

Comment: Thanks so much ive been working on this all day and it is finally working

Comment: If you need CONTROL over the playback then you need to throw out the extremely limited `playsound` module and find one that gives you control.  What you are doing here is hopeless hackery that is misusing system resources.

Comment: I have tested a lot of diffrent things but the only one that have worked well was playsound do you have any that you recomend ?